# Why does a UITableView data source get loaded after rows are created?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I have an interesting problem.

I am loading a UITableView asynchronously. I am trying to get the count:

```
prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSInteger dmCount = [prefs integerForKey:@"dmCount"];

NSLog(@"items count %d", [self.items count]); 

if (abs([self.items count] - dmCount) > 0) {
    [prefs setInteger:abs([self.items count] - dmCount)forKey:@"dmCount"];
}

NSLog(@"%d MESSAGES",abs([self.items count] - dmCount));
```

However, [self.items count] returns 0 when this code is executed, and then returns 4 (the actual value). I am guessing at the time of table creation my data source is 0, and once it has loaded it becomes 4. How can I make sure I get the correct count?

Comment: Where in your code is this? What is self.items and how does it get set? This code makes it hard to guess what is going on.

Comment: This code gets invoked in viewWillAppear. self.items is an NSMutableArray which is my data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i should count the item size in the didFinishConnection delegate method

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using Key-Value observing on the items property?